# A necessary condition for existence of Ricci flat metric on pair (X,D)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors

Let $X$ be a complex compact manifold with simple normal crossing divisor $D$. Is the condition $K_X +D = 0$   necessary for the existence of Ricci-flat metric?

Comment: Just to make this explicit, are you asking about *complete* Kaehler metrics that are Ricci flat?  If you do not demand completeness, then you can begin with a log Calabi-Yau open with a Ricci-flat metric, and then you can restrict to a smaller open by removing additional prime divisors. This will preserve the Ricci-flat condition, yet it destroys completeness.

Comment: It would be nice if some more effort was made in writing the question. $K_X+D=0$ in which sense? Linear equivalence? Ricci-flat metric on what? On $X$? On $X\setminus D$? In the latter case, complete or whatever? You suppose you manifold to be Kähler I guess? So, let's try to motivate people to answer your question by writing a *real* question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, the condition $K_X +D = 0$ is not necessary for the Ricci-flat case, when $D$ is singular. For instance,consider $X=\overline X\setminus D$ and take $\overline X=\mathbb CP^n$ and define the  divisor $D:=\{p(z)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}z_i=0\}$, where

$$f(z)=z_0^{m-1}z_n+P(z_0,...,z_{n-1})$$ for a homogeneous polynomial $P$ of degree $m\geq 2$. Then $X=(\mathbb C^*)^n$

After the comment of Jason, this example is for $D$ which is not snc divisor

Comment: The divisor that you wrote down is not a simple normal crossings divisor.  On the open affine where $z_n$ is nonzero, the defining equation dehomogenizes to $x_0x_1\dots x_{n-1}(x_0^{m-1} + P(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$.  The vanishing order at the origin of this defining equation (i.e., the largest integer $e$ such that the germ at the origin of the equation is in the $e^{\text{th}}$ power of the maximal ideal of the origin) equals $m+n-1$.  For the defining equation of a simple normal crossings divisor, the vanishing order is at most the dimension, i.e., $n$.